# unable to manual login after upgrading Ubuntu

Tags: lightdm, login-screen

I have upgraded my Ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10. And now after the system restart; there are only two options appears on screen as guest session and remote login.

How can I get back the manual login option in my login screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal (press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) at logon screen and enter below;

> sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults --show-manual-login true

Reboot the system or simply type `init 6` within the terminal itself to reboot.

Let us know here whether it works..

Answer (score 1):

`lightdm` is the default display manager in Ubuntu. somehow your default value of `lightdm` has been modified. you need to set it back to get back the login option.

First you need to login to a virtual console, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and enter your user-name and password.

Use the following command to set lightdm default values<sup>[[source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM)]</sup>,

```
$ sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults --show-manual-login true
$ sudo reboot
```

It will bring back the manual login option in your login screen after reboot.

**Alternate way**

you can edit your `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` by yourself and add the following line at the end,

```
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

To edit either you can open the file with `nano` or `vi` as,

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

or, just use the following in the console,

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "greeter-show-manual-login=true" >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf'
```

next reboot your system using, `sudo reboot`